# android - How to tell what resources are still loading?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have a webview in my Android app and sometimes it loads up perfectly but other times window.load() just never gets called and I have to refresh the webview a few times to get it to work.

Is there a way I can see what's still trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

Check WebViewClient:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        //get the url being loaded
    }

    public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
       //get the url of the resource being loaded
    }
}
```